# Yii2: Images stored in different tables

Tags: file-upload, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Here my controller:

```
    $model = new VehicleType();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if($model->validate()){

            $model->save();
            $id = $model->id;
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
            if($model->file){
                $id = $model->id;
                $imageName = "vehicletype_".$id.'_'.getdate()[0];
                $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);

                $station = VehicleType::findOne($id);
                $station->image = '@web/uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                $station->save();
            }
            return $this->redirect(['vehicletype/index']);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,

        ]);
    }
}
```

My view:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'station-form', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>              

                <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
                </div>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

        </div>
```

My model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['description'], 'string'],
        [['record_status'], 'integer'],
        [['name', 'image'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'image' => 'Image',
        'record_status' => 'Record Status',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getVehicles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Vehicles::className(), ['vehicle_type_id' => 'id']);
}
```

}

With this I can upload only one picture/post, I want one post to have multiple pictures, so I create a new table call '`Image`' to stored my pictures and have a one-to-many relationship.

But I run into a problem, how can I add data to 2 tables from just 1 form

I'm using Yii2 basic template

Thanks

Comment: what are the two tables where you want data to be inserted?

Comment: They are 'VerhicleType' with attribute 'id', 'name' and table 'IMG' with atribute 'id', 'image', and 'verhicletype_id' for one-to-many relationship

Comment: you have only three fields?

Comment: Yes, in verhicletype there are 'description' as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

First create two variables in your `vehicletype` model.

```
        public $uploadedImages;
        public $imageforNewtable = array();
```

**Step 2**

Make sure to mention this *imageforNewtable* variable in your model rule.

```
        [['imageforNewtable'], 'image', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, JPEG'],
```

**Step 3**

In your form:

```
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'station-form', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>


        <?= $form->field($model, 'imageforNewtable[]')->fileInput(['accept' => 'image/*']); ?>
```

**Step 4**

In Your Controller:

```
$model->uploadedImages = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'imageforNewtable');

        // Make sure to put "Instances" (plural of Instance) for uploading multiple images

$model->imageforNewtable = array(); // To avoid blank entries as we have entries in $_FILES not in $_POST.

            foreach ($model->uploadedImages as $singleImage) 
            {
            $model->imageforNewtable[] = time() . '_' . $singleImage->name;
            }
```

Now bulk insert data in **Images** table :

```
    $bulkInsertforimages = array(); //defined benchInsert array for images
    $columnsArray = ['blog_id', 'image']; //Column names in which bulk insert will take place.                
    if ($model->imageforNewtable != '') {
        foreach ($model->imageforNewtable as $singleData) {
            $bulkInsertforimages[] = [
                'blog_id' => $model->id,
                'image' => $singleData,
            ];
        }
    }


    if (count($bulkInsertforimages) > 0) {
        $command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand();
        $command->batchInsert('YOUR_IMAGE_TABLE', $columnsArray, $bulkInsertforimages)->execute();
    }
```

Comment: It worked :) but my file didn't get uploads to @web/uploads. How can I solved it?? @Sohil

Comment: Check the permissions of uploads folder